# What does "齓" mean?

Tags: translation, kanji, chinese

I've found this kanji during Shodo practice. My teacher (Japanese) didn't know the meaning (she recognized the Tooth bushu/radical but not the "word").

I tried to look it up on the electronic dictionaries I own, both Japanese and Chinese, but while the kanji exists and even has a phonetic associated to it:

[image: From Tangorin.com]

there is no actual meaning.

Finally I got something from a [Chinese online dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE9ZdicBDZdic93.htm).
Allegedly (I used Google translate on the whole page) it is an old ideogram for "Milk Teeth".

Now the question(s):

- Does this mean anything in Japanese?
- What would be the current Japanese way to indicate "Milk teeth"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The character in question was originally composed of 歯 (teeth) and 巳 (child). It represented children's teeth. This later became 齔 and 齓. 齔 is typically preferred over 齓, so I will use it below. It has two primary meanings: 1) in children, the replacement of old teeth with new teeth; 2) children of an age in which they are loosing their old teeth and growing new ones.

There are several compounds:

- 髫齔 (chōshin): a child around the age of 7 or 8
- 齔髫 (shinchō): (in general) a child
- 齔童 (shindō): children of an age in which they are loosing their old teeth and growing in new ones

Answer (score 8):

Kanjigen lists `齔{シン}` (U+9F54) together with `齓{シン}` (U+9F53), and as far as I can tell the former is more common, though I'm not sure either are commonly used (I think `乳歯{にゅうし}` might be much more common to mean "baby tooth").

It says it can refer to:

1. (シンす) (verb/noun) The losing of teeth which occurs around the age of 7 or 8. Or, the teeth one has prior to having them replaced (`乳歯{にゅうし}`).
2. (noun) A child which is aged when one loses teeth.

It also links to a similar Kanji which means "baby teeth": [`齠{チョウ}`](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E9%BD%A0) (U+9F60), though I'm not sure that's particularly common either.

[Kanjidic also defines](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E9%BD%94) `齔` (U+9F54) as "losing baby teeth"/"child" and [Unihan](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E9%BD%94) as "lose baby teeth and get adult teeth".

Comment: @p.marino jisho.org didn't list the meaning for [`齓`](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E9%BD%93), only for [`齔`](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E9%BD%94). I only found out the two were related after looking it up in Kanjigen.

Comment: Yep, thanks - I went through the same steps myself... but only after reading your answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer the first question, but deciduous/milk/baby teeth is [乳歯]{にゅうし}.

(Just a guess, but the reading かけば sounds like かけ + 歯(with rendaku), so I imagine it to be something like 欠け歯 but I cannot find anything to substantiate this claim.)

Comment: Not 掛け歯, but 欠け歯, meaning missing, broken, or chipped tooth. Maybe missing tooth is the translation that somewhat agrees with the notion of milk teeth...

Comment: @user1205935 I let the IME pick the kanji output. Maybe it's not broken/chipped tooth but "tooth that is lacking/insufficient" implying that the adult teeth is the better version?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I wonder in what sense 齓 is actually used in Japanese texts...